# Tensorflow 2.x compute and minimize loss (same step)

Tags: python, tensorflow

`opt.minimize(loss,vars=[...])` doesn't return a loss.

I could calculate loss after that, but then I evaluate the loss function twice.

How could i do a minimize and a loss computation in a "single" step, so that the loss is returned.

In Tensorflow 1.x one would do something like this:

```
train_op = Optimizer.minimize(loss)
sess.run([loss, train_op], feed_dict=feed)
```

How would I do this in Tensorflow 2

Comment: Does ``opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[...])`` work?

Answer (score 0):

One Solutios is to use gradient tape.

```
import tensorflow as tf
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
loss_fn = lambda: 3 * var1 * var1 + 2 * var2 * var2
var1 = tf.Variable(100.0)
var2 = tf.Variable(-2.0)


with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  loss = loss_fn() # alternativly some model.predict
  print(loss)
grads = tape.gradient(loss, [var1,var2])
opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, [var1,var2]))
print(var1.numpy())
print(var2.numpy())
```